# Display menu names in grid menu in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am developing a j2me application. In this application I am showing a grid menu.

I developed this menu using grid layout, I added buttons to the grid layout and it's working fine and this app will look like ICICI bank j2me app but the difference is in my app I am unable to show the menu names under the menu.

But I want to display names to this menu like ICICI bank java app...

**how to display menu names like in the following link?**

***[ICICI Bank j2me app sample](http://www.umnet.com/free-software/14750-ICICI_Imobile)***

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What are you using to create this grid menu? LCDUI? LWUIT? Canvas?

Comment: hi, I am using LWUIT to create this grid menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `form.addCommand(new Command("Item 1"));` etc. and read about commands. Once you have more than 2 a menu entry will form.